# laravel adds text to assets

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel

I have a laravel project on my localhost, but when i try to php artisan run it it starts up but my css and js are bugging. So first I checked the assets in my blade files but there was nothing weird. Then I used the inspect element from my browser and noticed that there is text added in every asset(css/js)

```
‹������
���������HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: localhost:8000
Date: Sat, 28 Apr 2018 14:34:17 +0200
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Length: 84345

/*! jQuery v2.1.4 | (c) 2005, 2015 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */
!function(a,b){"object"==typeof module&&"object"==typeof module.exports?module.exports=a.document?b(a,!0):function(a){if(!a.document)...
```

this is an example of such a corrupted file. When i check this file in my directory it doesnt show the extra information on the top. The way i implement my assets in my blade is the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/plugins/loaders/pace.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/core/libraries/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/core/libraries/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/plugins/loaders/blockui.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you use the helper

Comment: check your assets folder is public or not

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('assets/js/plugins/loaders/pace.min.js') }}"></script>

Comment: Did you run `npm run production`?

Comment: my folder is correctly set-up @SumanDey i tried to add assets/ in front of the code but without success.

Comment: @SaidbakR it give me an error but i never had to do this before. Normally i use the php artisan serve

Comment: message me https://www.facebook.com/mr.jarves then i help you better